# Передача значения переменной между классами

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Необходимо передать значение из переменной col(№1) в метку label(#2). Как это сделать? Где почитать об этом?

````
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
import numpy as np

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        uic.loadUi('untitled.ui', self)
        #2
        self.label.setText('__col')
        self.plotWater()
        self.plotFeed()

    def plotFeed(self):
        self.graphWidget.addItem(bg)

    def plotWater(self):
        self.graphWidget_2.addItem(bg4)


class BarGraph(pg.BarGraphItem):
    def mouseClickEvent(self, event):
        print("Координаты: x=", event.pos().x(), "; y=", event.pos().y())
        #1
        self.col = round(event.pos().x())
        #print('__column =', __column)

        # self.labelEditRequest= (label.setText(self.col))
        # labelEdit(self.labelEditRequest)


x = np.arange(10)
y1 = x

bg = BarGraph(x=x, y=y1 - 0.5 * x, height=y1, width=0.8)
bg4 = BarGraph(x=x, y=y1 - 0.5 * x, height=y1, width=0.8)

MainWindow.plotFeed
MainWindow.plotWater


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    MainWindow.graphWidget.scene().sigMouseClicked.connect(onClick) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант №1 (Кутишный):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

class BarGraph(pg.BarGraphItem):
    # Сигнал передачи значения из колонки
    signal_columnValueChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def mouseClickEvent(self, event):
        self.col = round(event.pos().x())
        # сигнализируем об изменении
        self.signal_columnValueChanged.emit(self.col)
```

Тогда в главном окне надо просто слушать этот сигнал:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def plotFeed(self):
        bg.signal_columnValueChanged.connect(self.__columnValueChanged)
        self.graphWidget.addItem(bg)

    def __columnValueChanged(self, columnValue):
        self.label.setText(str(columnValue))
```

Для метода plotWater аналогично и слот для получения значения тот же (если так и задумано). 
Кроме того, можно сделать слот через lambda:

```
bg.signal_columnValueChanged.connect(lambda col: self.label.setText(str(col)))
```

Вариант №2 (Явовский через слушателя):

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def plotFeed(self):
        bg.setListener(self)
        self.graphWidget.addItem(bg)

    def plotWater(self):
        bg4.setListener(self)
        self.graphWidget_2.addItem(bg4)

    # Метод для получения значения колонки
    def columnChanged(self, col):
        self.label.setText(str(col))
```

Надо добавить функцию setListener в класс:

```
class BarGraph(pg.BarGraphItem):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.BarGraphItem.__init__(self)
        self.__listener = None

    def setListener(self, listener):
        self.__listener = listener

    def mouseClickEvent(self, event):
        self.col = round(event.pos().x())
        if self.__listener not is None:
            self.__listener.columnChanged(self.col)
```